# Cocoa : Displaying battery percentage in the menu bar

Tags: macos, cocoa, battery

In terminal the following command enables the battery percentage in the menu bar :

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.battery ShowPercent -string "YES"
```

How should this be done programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any program (such as `defaults`) using the [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Alternatively you could search the plist file in `~/Libraries/Preferences`, read it into an `NSMutableDictionary`, change the `ShowPercent` value and write it back.